# Trigonometric question involving similar triangles

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

[image]

**The $\alpha$ angle is supposed to be 90.00 degrees**. Couldn't get it right with the graph tool!

I'm trying to understand why the **CK** segment isn't

$$
CK = CJ*cos(Y)
\\
CK = CJ*\frac{CA}{CB}
$$

and the correct answer is (using similar triangles relationships):

$$
\frac{CA}{CJ} = \frac{CB}{CK}
\\
CK = CJ*\frac{CB}{CA}
$$

equivalent to

$$
CK = CJ*\frac{1}{cos(Y)}
$$

Comment: What's odd to me is that the CN segment does work if I do CM * cos(Y), assuming CM = CA/2

Comment: $\frac{CA}{CB}\ne \cos(\gamma)$ because $\Delta ABC$ is not a right triangle.

Comment: @JohnJoy Sorry, the $\alpha$ angle is supposed to be 90 degrees. Just made a clarification!

Comment: Sorry, this one went by me the first time that I looked at it. I think that the "correct" answer may be incorrect. $\Delta CJK$ is similar to $\Delta CBA$, so the equation should be $$\frac{CA}{CK}= \frac{CB}{CJ}$$